# Is there a word that means - of or related to books?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am expecting a word like bovine (of or related to cattle) and sartorial (relating to tailoring, clothes, or style of dress).

My intention is to to use it like:

> Goodreads helps me to fulfil my ___ needs.
>
> My _____ needs have not yet been met this month.

Comment: Probably *folial* or *foliar,* but those are a bit close to *foliage,* which is only loosely related to books. I can't think of a sentence where such a word would actually be required; generally "of books" or "in books" would be said. Could you have a look at the [SWR tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and its checklist, please? A sample sentence really helps.

Comment: There's the prefix *biblio-* which is "of or related to books"... but I can't find a standalone word with the same meaning.

Comment: "literary" is frequently used although some may argue that not all books are 'literature' (if they have a narrow sense of the word) or that some 'literature' might include magazines or periodicals(in the broad sense of the word)

Comment: ... Do you have a sample sentence where you would like to use this word?

Comment: @Hellion: It doesn't have its own separate entry, but OED mentions [***bibliophagist***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18620) under its entry for the ***biblio-*** prefix. So if OP considers himself to have a "voracious appetite" for books, and doesn't mind employing a noun adjunct form, *My bibliophagist needs must be satisfied.*

Comment: How about bookish? Can you do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could stretch the word ***bibliophilic*** to fit your sample sentences. It's not a direct equivalent to sartorial etc, but I think it would be well understood in the context. One [definition](http://www.definitions.net/definition/bibliophilic) is "having, or pertaining to, bibliophilia (the love of books)."

Answer (score 1):

@Tom22 is right in the comments. I think "literary" is the closest you can come, but refers to literature ("written works, especially those considered of superior or lasting artistic merit." according to Google) which is not exactly the same as books.

Comment: Please never use code markup on ELU: we have no computer code here.

Answer (score 0):

The word ***Bookish*** fits your request precisely. [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookish) gives the first definition as:

> 1: a : of or relating to books

The one caveat I would give is that, I have often heard it used to mean *learned*, or *fond of reading*. But those definitions are generally used when describing a person as bookish. I don't think that it would be ambiguous in your example sentences.

It isn't as grand sounding as *bibliophilic*, but it is more general.

Comment: For balance, the list-by-frequency-of-usage dictionaries Collins and RHK Webster's give that sense last, while AHD, Lexico, CD, Macmillan and Wiktionary see it as best omitted.